# Include blank elements in for...each loop in Classic ASP

Tags: url, vbscript, asp-classic, query-string

I'm trying to convert a VBScript array to a querystring to include as a Get in a URL. I've got:

```
function array_to_querystring( arrParams )
    dim x : x=1
    for each param in arrParams
        array_to_querystring = "&" & x & "=" & param
        x=x+1
    next
end function
```

The problem is that sometimes an element is an empty string, and I DO want to include that, but my code drops those.

So if I call `array_to_querystring( array( "", "hello" ) )` I get:

```
&2=hello
```

What I want is:

```
&1=&2=hello
```

The for...each loop is dropping params that are empty string. Any idea how to force it to include them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not because of the empty string, but because you are assigning the value to the function name in each iteration.

You should keep adding to a string in each iteration and then assign the string to the function name after the loop.

```
function array_to_querystring( arrParams )
    dim x : x=1
    dim output : output=""
    for each param in arrParams
        output = output & "&" & x & "=" & param
        x=x+1
    next

    array_to_querystring = output
end function
```

Comment: ::facepalm::  it's been one of those days

Comment: :) Happens to everyone.